# Load dropdown with Database Data

Tags: sql, winforms, combobox

I'm new in windows forms and I have `comboBox` called `cbTasks` and I want to populate it in load window so I execute sql task as:

```
  private void StatusForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var db = new SQLConnMgr();

            var taskType = string.Format("SELECT [Name], [Id] FROM [TaskType] WHERE TaskTypeCategoryId = {0} ", TaskTypeCategoryId);
            var taskList = db.GetTableBySQL(taskType);



        }
```

As you can see I have items into `taskList` variable, but now I want to fill `comboBox`. How can I achieve that? I try to use `foreach` but I don't know how to call [Name] into Add method:

```
  foreach(DataRow task in taskList.Rows)
                {
                   cbTasks.Items.Add()
                }
```

How can I achieve that? Regards

Comment: Remove the foreach.  Set `cbTasks.DataSource = taskList;`  Then set `cbTasks.DisplayMember = "Name";`  `cbTasks.ValueMember = "Id";`

Comment: Working!. Thankyou! @LarsTech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind tghe datatable to the dropdown, the dot new framework does the looping for you behind the scenes:

```
cbTasks.DataSource = taskList; 
cbTasks.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
cbTasks.ValueMember = "Id";
```